# Creating a table through local storage data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

How can I populate my table with an array of local storage data?

```
function savePlayer() {
    let Player = {player,score};
    localStorage.setItem("Player", JSON.stringify(Player));

    let getPlayerScore = Player;
    let text = document.getElementById("topScores");

    for(let i = 0; i <Player.length; i++){
        text += "<tr>";
        text += "<td>" + getPlayerScore[i].player + "</td>";
        text += "<td>" + getPlayerScore[i].score + "</td></tr>";
    }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
 <body>
 <table id = "topScores">
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr>

        </table>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is 'get' word is save words , try to change to something other , like: 

`let getPlayerScore = ....`

Comment: @MarinTerziyski still doesn't work unfortunately. I cannot understand whats going on.

Comment: @Sarah you have pasted the javascript code twice. The HTML is missing ... Also what is the error or the result that you are getting ?

Comment: `let get = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(Player.toString()));
let create = JSON.parse(get); ` why you parse it twice , you've already parsed it in decalration of get ?

Comment: @MarinTerziyski I've edited it check it out. Still not working!

Comment: @Fiorila Edited it.

Comment: try to change and this code : Player.toString() --> JSON.stringify(Player) , but I think you've already did it , when it set the localStorage . Maybe your data is already string :) Try to check it in developerTools -> application -> localStorage

Comment: I removed it. Nothing changes...the table still wont show up :(

Comment: You should append your new items , not add them like text. Check whats happening in your DOM

Comment: @MarinTerziyski Do you have an example with the code I provided.

Answer (score 1):

The `Player.toString()` isn't what you think it is.

```js
var player = "Mario";
var score = 1000;
var Player = {
  player,
  score
};
// Print Player
console.log(JSON.stringify(Player));
console.log(Player.toString());
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. But how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just add text to an element; you need to set it though 
`innerHTML`. Sadly, however, you can't set it for each row, because the DOM will try to end the `tr` tag, so you need to set everything at the same time through a string.

I couldn't get localStorage to work in the snippet so I commented out the code without testing it.

Another solution would be to append the elements, and honestly, that's what I would prefer, but I didn't want to steer to far away from your original solution, and I didn't want fix the "feature" where the DOM is autocompleting `tr` tags.

```js
function savePlayer() {
     // This wasn't an array to begin with, so I fixed that.
    let Player = [{"player": "player","score": 10}];
    
     // It's usually preferred to refer to a public constant when accessing localStorage.
    let localStorageKey = "player";
/*    localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(Player));

    let getPlayerScore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey));*/

    let getPlayerScore = Player;
    let text = document.getElementById("topScores");
    var playerRow = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < getPlayerScore.length; i++){
        playerRow = "<tr>";
        playerRow += "<td>" + getPlayerScore[i].player + "</td>";
        playerRow += "<td>" + getPlayerScore[i].score + "</td></tr>";
    }
    
    text.innerHTML += playerRow;
}
```

```html
<body onload="savePlayer()">
 <table id="topScores">
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```